# How to add GData.framework in my iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, gdata-api, youtube-api

I'm just giving it a shot to learn objective C and Cocoa and play
aound with the Google APIs.
I am trying to follow the instructions on the main page to include the
framework within my application but I'm not having much luck.

Would someone be able to provide some instuctions with a bit more
detail?

I would greatly appreciate it.

I've added the GData.xcodeproj under my main application and added a
direct dependency to GData under  Target->myApp

I keep getting the following error:

```
cd "/Users/ankushgupta/Xcode Projects/Google Test"
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/
pbxcp -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -strip-debug-
symbols -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/ankushgupta/Xcode\ Projects/Google\
Test/build/Release/GData.framework /Users/ankushgupta/Xcode\ Projects/Google
\ Test/build/Release/Google\ Test.app/Contents/Frameworks
pbxcp: GData.framework: No such file or directory
```

I'm kind of lost and I really need to get this setup so I can learn
the API and do some real coding :(

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the Objective-C Google API source code from

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

and compile it from the included xCode project. The included documentation explains in detail how to either link statically, include framework or reference the Google API code directly from your project.

I choose to include all the source code I need directly in my project by reference to the original Google files. Include the source files by dragging them into you xCode project.

I wouldn't recommend the Google API's for learning to program the iPhone. It would be complicating the learning process unnecessarily.